# Accessing array elements in codeigniter using keys with \ in them

Tags: codeigniter-3

My code is:

```
public function dirNames()  
{ 
 $maps = directory_map('./application',2);      
 print_r($maps);    
}
```

I got an array like this:

```
Array ( [cache\] => Array ( [0] => index.html ) 
        [config\] => Array ( [0] => autoload.php 
                             [1] => config.php 
                             [2] => constants.php 
                             [3] => database.php 
                             [4] => doctypes.php 
                             [5] => foreign_chars.php 
                             [6] => hooks.php 
                             [7] => index.html 
                             [8] => memcached.php 
                             [9] => migration.php 
                             [10] => mimes.php 
                             [11] => profiler.php 
                             [12] => routes.php 
                             [13] => smileys.php 
                             [14] => user_agents.php ) )
```

And I am trying to access the values and print them like this in my next step:
`print_r($maps['cache\'])`;

So, it is showing an error like this:

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: ParseError
Message: syntax error, unexpected ''cache\']); ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']'
Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\application\controllers\Practice_controller.php
Line Number: 33
Backtrace:
File: D:\xampp\htdocs\practice\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

My question is, how we can access values based on this type of keys? Please help me.

> cache\

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

access them by adding `backslash` ('\') as below :

```
$maps = directory_map('./application',2); 

/* for cache*/ 
print_r($maps['cache\\']);

/* for config*/
print_r($maps['config\\']);
```